# Is it possible to execute some code when an item from an HTML5 datalist has been selected?

Tags: javascript, html, events, html-datalist

For example:

```
<input type="text" list="sample"/>
<datalist id="sample">
    <option value="item 1"/>
    <option value="item 2"/>
</datalist>
```

Is it possible to catch the event when an item from the datalist had been selected? Calling onclick or onchange on the input element don't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#search").on("input", function(e) {
var val = $(this).val();
if(val === "") return;
....
    var dataList = $("#searchresults");
dataList.empty();
 your code...

}); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me half way there, since "input" is fired when a datalist item is selected, which i didn't know how to acomplish before. Furthermore, is there a way to distinguish when a datalist item was selected from a normal typing event? With this current code, the event is fired when a datalist item has been selected, as well as when the user is typing and also when text was pasted into the input field (mouse only).

Answer (score 0):

`Datalist` is used for a `storage and Auto list Purpose`... It `doesn't have Selected Events`..

if you want to get the items in datalist... just loop it and get the data...

```
$('#sample option').each(function(index) {
 alert($(this).val());
});
```